# Access to request from origin has been blocked by CORS policy. Email sending failed with this error

Tags: javascript, html, css, cors

I am not able to send email from my website (developed using `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript`).

I get following error message when i send email:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://mobilfiksern.no/contactform.php'  from origin 'http://www.mobilfiksern.no' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Can any one please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: I guess the issue is because of www subdomain?

Comment: need to add headers

Comment: can you change your url from http://mobilfiksern.no/contactform.php to http://www.mobilfiksern.no/contactform.php  this and retry.

Comment: @ShireeshaParampalli what headers I should add?

Comment: @Ved both of these are the same URLs, what url i should change?

Answer (score 0):

Every page top, or common top php file please add the following line.

```
<?php
//Session start section
?>    
<?php

//Need to add the following codes
$origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
// PHP 7.x version array
$allowed_domains = ['http://mobilfiksern.no','http://www.mobilfiksern.no'];
// PHP 5.x version array
//$allowed_domains = array("http://mobilfiksern.no", "http://www.mobilfiksern.no");

if (in_array($origin, $allowed_domains)) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
}
?>
<?php
//Usual codes
?>
<?php //Start the html tags ?>
<html>
```

Comment: This is not working for me.
Problem is in Ajex request. If I comment code with Ajex request then no error message but email is also not send then. with Ajex request there is error of CORS